# How high up should I put the ice maker connection box?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, ice-maker

I'm going to finally connect the refrigerator's ice maker to water. Because the water line will come from the basement (and not from a kitchen cabinet), I have bought this connection box to install in the wall behind the fridge ([Data sheet](http://www.oatey.com/doc/I2K%20Submittal.pdf)):

[image: Ice maker connection box]

But **how high up on the wall should I put the box**? Is there a standard height?

Comment: I think most fridges have their connections down low, so I'd probably put it about the same height as the receptacles in the house (12-16" to the top). Not sure if there's a standard height.  If the receptacle for the fridge is down low, I'd probably line it up with that. You'll not usually see it, but when the fridge is pulled out it will look nice and uniform.

Comment: I ended up putting it next to the receptacle, which was about counter height. It looks neat, and the helps keep the water line from being run over when the fridge is pushed into its nook.

Answer (score 7):

I would not put it low.  I recommend it being above the adjacent counter height so you don't have to pull the fridge all the way out to turn the shut off valve and bend down.  4'-0" aff is my answer.  Nobody cares what it looks like once the fridge is in place.  It will be all about convenience and repairs.

Comment: Yep, and even if you have to pull the fridge out, down low is a PITA to reach (crouching), so even chest height would be good.  (I guess 48" could be chest height, depending how tall one is!)

Answer (score 0):

4 feet is a good height. Don’t put it to low.

Answer (score 0):

Refrigerator inlet water valve located at the very bottom of the fridge. So it make sense to locate wall water valve on the same level, so when you need to pull out the fridge water hose will be laying horizontal on the floor, not hanging diagonal from 4ft up the wall and be on your way. Also diagonal hose will be shorter so you may not pull fridge far enough from the wall to easy access for repair or cleaning. 4 feet up the wall make sense only for washing machine. I am appliance repair tech.